# Does Redemittel have a singular?

Tags: grammatical-number

According to [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lang=de&search=mittel):

- *Das Mittel*, sg. (means; aid) has the plural form *die Mittel*.
- *Die Mittel*, pl. (capital; funds) lacks a singular form.

Which kind of *Mittel* is *die Redemittel*? Does it exist in singular?

Comment: I think it's something like "money" as you've mentioned "funds". So singular and plural form are equal.

Comment: Redemittel ist aber nicht allgemein gebräuchlich. Ich hab es noch nicht gehört.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Redemittel* (also: sprachliche Mittel) is both singular and plural. It derives from [Mittel](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mittel) as in **means**.

> Er benutzt ein sprachliches Mittel
>
> Er benutzt viele sprachliche Mittel